# Система не обнаружила opencv_world490d.dll C++ в Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

ОШИБКА:

[image: ошибка]

Тут я добавил в **Additional Dependencies** путь из OpenCV.
[image: aditional]

В **Include** тоже добавил

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же и в **Library Directories**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я все добавил, но все ровно ошибка что не так ?

Comment: Вы добавили .lib файлы в параметры сборки. А ругается на .dll при запуске.

Comment: @user7860670 А как решить эту проблему ?

Comment: Подкладывайте нужные .dll чтобы их мог находить исполняемый файл при запуске.

Comment: @user7860670 а не знаете где их можно найти?

Comment: Наверное где-то рядом с .lib файлами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ОС Windows не позволяет  прописать путь к динамической библиотеке (dll), по-этому самый простой способ - это скопировать её в папку проекта Visual Studio.
К сожалению, я не знаком с OpenCV, но думаю, что Вы можете найти необходимые библиотеки в папке lib или bin этого проекта.